# Link to resources

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I run eclipse ADT IDE on Ubuntu 12.04. After I click on some resource ID (with CTRL pressed) it doesn't load right resource for me (instead eclipse opens the generated R.java file). How force it to open directed resource file?

When I run eclipse under Windows then the IDE can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **this is not possible with Eclipse**. It is one of the reasons why the Android team moved to Android Studio (based on Intellij) because you can do this sort of thing with this IDE.